# Chrome won't save changes to SCSS fle

Tags: google-chrome

I'm trying to edit .scss in-browser with Chrome, but saving does not write the changes to the local file.

I also get this error:

> The "Last-Modified" response header is missing or invalid for
>   file:///Users/Jet/Repo/css/style.scss.
>   The CSS auto-reload functionality will not work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistake. When you initially click save, Chrome autofills the file name 'style' and does not include the .scss file extension. Make sure you add that!